# JQuery Tools 1.2.7 (and 1.2.8 development) first tab not being loaded

Tags: ajax, tabs, jquery-tools

I have tried using JQuery Tools 1.2.7 ajaxed tabs, but for some reason the first tab does not load by default. I have to click on any other tab then return to the first tab for it to be loaded and displayed.

Looking at their demo here:
http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/ajax-history.html

In the demo it's the same thing, I have to go to the second or third tab then when I return to the first tab it will be loaded, it doesn't get loaded when the page is being loaded...

In orther words I'm experiencing the same issue as this guy:
http://jquerytools.org/forum/tools/25/99227

Is there a solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to resolve this issue by adding "$("div.css-panes > div").load('ajax1.htm')" to the "activate tabs with JavaScript" function:

```
$(function() {
    $("ul.css-tabs").tabs(
        "div.css-panes > div",
        {effect: 'ajax', history: false}
        );
    $("div.css-panes > div").load('ajax1.htm');
    });
```

in the jQuery Tools example (http://jquerytools.org/demos/tabs/ajax-history.htm).

Comment: Thanks alot, this did the job :) I had a big issue with the previous jquery-tools version 1.2.6, this seems to have also solved it :)